# Clean alternative to Binding's now-deprecated Collection conformance?

Tags: collections, binding, swiftui

[As of Xcode 11 beta 6…](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos_release_notes/macos_catalina_10_15_beta_6_release_notes)

> The Binding structure’s conditional conformance to the Collection protocol is removed.

Going with Apple's recommendation (at that link) of creating an `IndexedCollection` type, we can avoid boilerplate for `List` and `ForEach` like this:

```swift
public extension ForEach where Content: View {
  init<Base: RandomAccessCollection>(
    _ base: Base,
    @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (Data.Element) -> Content
  )
  where
    Data == IndexedCollection<Base>,
    Base.Element: Identifiable,
    ID == Base.Element.ID
  {
    self.init(IndexedCollection(base: base), id: \.element.id, content: content)
  }
}
```

That takes us from their example,

```swift
List(landmarks.indexed(), id: \.1.id) { index, landmark in
  Toggle(landmark.name, isOn: self.$landmarks[index].isFavorite)
}
```

to this:

```swift
List(landmarks) { index, landmark in
  Toggle(landmark.name, isOn: self.$landmarks[index].isFavorite)
}
```

But is it possible to write another extension initializer, to allow for avoiding having to use the index and subscript (`self.$landmarks[index]`)?

I've tried making use of `dynamicMemberLookup`, but if that's the solution, I didn't get it right yet.